# Hosting an Asp.Net MVC 4 application on windows server 2012 with IIS8 from a Local Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I have developed an MVC 4 application on my personal laptop and would like to host it onto a windows 2012 server so that it goes live.

What I am doing right now is, I have published the application as a File System in my laptop and then remote logged in to the windows 2012 Server and trying to deploy it into IIS 8 which is on that server but I could find a way to import my application into the server.

Now, my question is do I need to install Visual Studio 2012 on the server and then copy my application over to it and then publish and deploy or is there any other way.

This is the first time I am deploying and hosting an application. So, I am not sure of the exact procedure to do it.

Remember that my development machine is not the windows server but it is my personal laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) (a free Microsoft Tool) on your target server. Then you can deploy your site directly from VS. See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you but do I need to copy my application over to server

Comment: No. Visual Studio will do it by itself.

Comment: I was trying it and it said that "could not connect to remote computer using the specified process ("Web Management Service" )because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service" ) is started on the remote computer"

Comment: Could be disabled. Run InetMgr.exe on the server, on the server node select Management Service in the tree view and enable by clicking Enable remote connections. Also please check if this service is started

Comment: @vzayko - WebDeploy is not exactly a simple installation.. I've tried dozens of times and can never seem to get it configured correctly...